# Why is my page Javascript not working when I serve my HTML through a Node server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server

When I launch the HTML page via the Node server (i.e., navigate to localhost:3000 in the browser), nothing prints to the console as I would expect based on the page Javascript file (see below).  However, when I open the HTML file directly from the folder, "Hi" prints to the console as expected.

Here's the Node server Javascript:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    http.createServer(function (request, response) {
         response.statusCode = 200;
         response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
         response.write(html);
         response.end();
    }).listen(3000);
    console.log('Server is running!!');
})
```

Here's the page HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="page.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the page Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Hi")
});
```

Comment: How does page.js get loaded? Check your network tab of your browser. It's probably not being loaded. You have no route for static assets or for the page.js specifically, right?

Comment: The network tab (Firefox) says it's being loaded with a 200 status.  Not sure what you mean by "route for static assets," but page.js is linked through the <script> tag.

Comment: I would suggest removing page.js and loading jquery from a CDN so you can verify that it is loading correctly. 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah In your server above, there is no way for it to serve page.js. Maybe it is returning 200 but now go look at what the actual response was for page.js -- it'll be the contents of index.html.

Comment: To fix that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756459/routing-http-requests-through-node-js for how to use node http module and do routing. Or try KoaJS or Express or one of the other solutions that have routing or ways to do routing. But you can do it with vanilla http as linked earlier in this response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to branch by the requested URL in your server. Right now, when your browser loads the page, it'll get the contents of index.html. However, when it requests page.js, it'll get the contents of index.html not the contents of page.js. For how to do routing, which means looking to see what was requested and responding by the request, see [Routing http requests through Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756459/routing-http-requests-through-node-js).

You can use the vanilla HTTP module and do it that way or you can bring in a framework like KoaJS or Express which have helpers for routing and other things. Which is appropriate depends on your needs and wants (for pure learning, vanilla is great).